# Using CRM form instead of RadScheduler Advanced Form

Tags: telerik, dynamics-crm-2011, radscheduler

I need to integrate the Telerik RadScheduler control with CRM 2011. Is there a way I can use a CRM form of a custom entity instead of the Scheduler's Advanced Edit form ? i.e. When I double click the appointment in the Scheduler the corresponding custom entity form is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a silverlight component on a CRM form which can have your telerik control included. We have done this a number of times including using the scheduler control you are talking about

Comment: yes but i need it the other way around. After placing the control in the CRM, I need to be able to open a CRM Form by double-clicking the appointment on the telerik scheduler

Comment: You can do that two ways, one is to construct the URL from the record GUID and type code or if you have access to the XRM context you can use the the Crm.Utility.openEntityForm method